# display jsf 2D table

Tags: jsf

I want to display a 2D array in my view .xhtml, which contains the database column as rows, but I can not get a 2D array

my BD Table

```
training | experience | motivation
NA       | B          | AT
```

I want to display a data table as follows

```
                | evaluation | comment
-------------------------------------------
training        | A          | ...
-------------------------------------------------- -----
experience      | B          | ....
```

Comment: How would you do this when displaying it via system.out.println? Transposing the data first (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569266/how-to-change-row-to-column-in-datatable, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582010/flipped-over-datatable-primefaces, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620513/how-to-output-data-of-primefaces-datagrid-component-by-columns-instead-of-by-row, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315357/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-rows-with-jsf-hdatatable) ... Do the same  here

Comment: no, in my view .xhtml

Comment: Like mentioned, you can't do it in the view, transpose it in the bean/model

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write some Java code in a managed bean like this:

```
public class SomethingSomethingDTO {
    private final String subject;
    private final String evaluation;
    private final String comment;

    public SomethingSomethingDTO(final String subject, 
            final String evaluation, final String comment) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.evaluation = evaluation;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public String getEvaluation() {
        return evaluation;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

}

@PostConstruct // or some other event or command button action
public void initializeSomething() {
    somethings = new ArrayList<>();
    somethings.add(new SomethingSomethingDTO("training", "A", "..."));
    somethings.add(new SomethingSomethingDTO("experiance", "B", "..."));
}

private List<SomethingSomethingDTO> somethings;

public List<SomethingSomethingDTO> getSomethings() {
    return somethings;
}
```

Comment: This was not in one of the links @Kukeltje provided?

Comment: Not this concrete and simple example way, yes. Some solutions involved adding component libraries (t:datatable) or overriding a renderer.